# Conditional creation of a resource based on a variable in .tfvars.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, conditional-statements, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I have to create RDS with data encryption enabled in the multi-region. When RDS creating I need to enable  `"storage_encrypted": true,` and when encryption is enabled AWS required multi-region support `kms_key_id` to create global RDS.

There are two scenarios I have to validate before creating the RDS.

1. When `storage_encrypted": true,` get the `"kms_key_id" : "arn:aws:kms:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",` create a RDS.
2. If `storage_encrypted": false,` get the default kms_key_id key and create RDS with validating a condition.

How can I make conditions for the above scenario?

In the `variables.tf`

```
variable "storage_encrypted" {
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "kms_key_id" {
  type        = string
  default     = null
}
```

In the `vars.tfvars.json` file I have two parameters.

```
"storage_encrypted" : true,   
"kms_key_id" : "arn:aws:kms:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
```

This is the current `aurora.tf` module for secondary

```
module "aurora_secondary" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws"
  version = "7.3.0"

  apply_immediately   = var.apply_immediately
  create_cluster = var.create_secondary_cluster
  providers = { aws = aws.secondary }

  is_primary_cluster = false  
  source_region             = var.primary_region

  name           = var.name

  engine                    = var.create_global_cluster ? aws_rds_global_cluster.this.*.engine[0] : null
  engine_version            = var.create_global_cluster ? aws_rds_global_cluster.this.*.engine_version[0] : null
  global_cluster_identifier = var.create_global_cluster ? aws_rds_global_cluster.this.*.id[0] : null
  
  *********************************************
  storage_encrypted     = var.storage_encrypted
  *********************************************

  create_random_password              = var.create_random_password

  instance_class = var.instance_class
  instances = var.secondary_instances


  vpc_id                 = var.vpc_id_us_east_2
  create_db_subnet_group = var.create_secondary_db_subnet_group
  subnets  = var.private_subnets_us_east_2
  create_security_group  = var.create_secondary_security_group
  allowed_cidr_blocks    = var.allowed_cidr_blocks

  
  create_monitoring_role                = var.create_monitoring_role
  monitoring_interval                   = var.monitoring_interval
  monitoring_role_arn                   = var.monitoring_role_arn

  backup_retention_period = var.backup_retention_period
  preferred_backup_window = var.preferred_backup_window
  preferred_maintenance_window = var.preferred_maintenance_window

  depends_on = [
    module.aurora
  ]

  tags = local.cluster_tags
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? What is your current attempt to solve the issue and why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin
`Error: creating RDS Cluster (ssw-invoice-prod): InvalidParameterCombination: For encrypted cross-region replica, kmsKeyId should be explicitly specified` 

I want to create validation conditions as I mention above

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "get the default kms_key_id key and create RDS with validating a condition"? Get the key id from where? What does it mean "validating a condition" - what condition?

Comment: 1. When creating RDS in AWS, there is a required `Key Management Service (KMS) key`  you can see it on the already created RDS by clicking the `configuration tab` and checking under `AWS KMS key`. It's Automatically assigned the default KMS key, it supports only a single region. But when we create multi-region RDS we have to create a multi-region support KMS key.

Comment: 2. RDS with validating a condition - As I explained above there are two items I have to validate before creating RDS. The first one is I have to check `storage_encrypted: true`, if encryption is `true` I have to get the multi-region support KMS key and create a resource from the multi-region support KMS key.

If `storage_encrypted: false` create a resource from the single-region support KMS key, which is the default KMS key.

So I have to implement some way of validating the above scenarios.